# Reboot on using Microsoft remote desktop

Tags: ubuntu, reboot, rdp

I have a raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu. Most of the times I connect to it using Microsoft remote desktop, it hangs and then reboots after some time. Has anybody seen this? How can I find out why the Pi rebooted or how can this be avoided? I am using the official power supply from Raspberry Pi and there is no under voltage being reported in syslog.

Comment: look in the log files in `/var/log`

Comment: Nothing there as well. Ran grep on the folder.

Comment: `Ran grep on the folder` ... what did you look for? the time of the reboot?

Comment: Looked for voltage, temperature and power. No sign of these keywords.

Comment: I'd look for logs around the time the pi rebooted